# How to run Visual Studio Cordova Projects on iOS?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Is there a way to test an app on iOS device which is developed in Cordova Visual Studio? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test your Cordova app on an iOS device, but you'll need a mac computer to build your app. Visual Studio offers options to do this depending on your operating system:

- If you're already using a mac you can run your app [using parallels](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build_ios_parallels/)
- If you're working on windows you'll have to build your app on a [mac remote agent](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/) or on a [cloud service](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build_ios_cloud) like [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Cordova Visual Studio to build iOS, Android and Windows app. Visual Studio itself provides preview support for many emulators which you can use for testing. Additionally, visual studio can connect to any target. It can be emulator or simulator or iOS device itself.

Visual Studio provides multiple options for testing Cordova apps on iOS.

- Apache Ripple simulator, which provides basic validation of layout and CSS. This is good as this does not require installation of the remote agent for iOS.
- iOS Simulator, which requires installation and configuration of the
  remote agent when running from Visual Studio.
- iOS Simulator using a service such as MacInCloud, which allows you to
  install the remote agent without a physical Mac device.
- iOS device, which also requires installation and configuration of the
  remote agent when running from Visual Studio.

Our team had worked in past used simulator mostly to test iOS but please refer to https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/ to find more information.